# Delete an App from chartboost?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, chartboost

I have a added my app in Chartboost for my iOS app. But by mistake a have created two apps. Now I am unable to find out a way to delete it.
Please tell me is there any way to delete it?

Answer (score 2):

To delete an App from Chartboost you need to contact them with Chartboost app ID.

**Below is what i found on there site.**
**Ref : https://answers.chartboost.com/hc/en-us/articles/201121869**

How can I delete an app from the dashboard?

Last Update: December 18, 2014 06:47
Please contact us with the Chartboost app ID you'd like removed from your account – we'd be happy to help you out!

You need to contact them using URL :
https://answers.chartboost.com/hc/en-us/requests/new